# Replace all occurences of two spaces after the end of a sentence with just one space

Tags: text-processing, sed

I'm stuck in including regular expressions with a sed command.

**Q:** I want to replace all occurences of two spaces after the **end of a sentence** with just once space.

**Here is what I did:**

```
sed 's/^ $/^$/' file
```

And it didn't substituted two spaces with a one space after the sentence ends.

**Output I get:**

```
This is the output.  Hello Hello
```

**Output I want:**

```
This is the output. Hello Hello
```

Comment: @Rahul I want the output with that contains once space after the sentence ends. Not two spaces as in first sentence. I want the second sentence output

Comment: The answer by @Jasen is correct. BTW, the command you tried means: Substitute a line consisting of only a single whitspace by an empty line. This is why it did not do what you wanted.

Comment: *Insert here: war on single vs. double space after full stop*

Comment: @gerrit That war was lost some 20 years ago. ;)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
 sed 's/\.   */. /g' < file
```

replace dot followed by two or more spaces with dot followed 
by a single space.

Comment: Your command actually works for the whole paragraph. That's exactly what I wanted. Thanks!

Comment: or `sed -r 's/\.\s+/. /g' file` with GNU sed...

Comment: @spasic use `sed -E` rather than `sed -r`.  That works with GNU sed and *BSD sed (incl. Mac OS X) and some others.  It's scheduled for inclusion as standard in POSIX "real soon now".

Comment: @cas I remember sometime back, I suggested `sed -E` to someone on this site which didn't work but `sed -r` worked.. I've worked with GNU sed alone, so no idea on POSIX and other variations.. will try to include this detail in future, thanks :)

Comment: It must have been an old version of GNU sed.  They've supported `-E` for quite a while now (since at least 2011, but the man and info pages still only mention `-r`)

Answer (score 13):

Your `sed` command `'s/^ $/^$/'` won't do what you want. It just replace all lines contains one space with a line contain `^$`.

Depend on what characters mark end of sentence, you can do:

```
sed -e 's/\([.?!]\) \{2,\}/\1 /g' <file
```

This will replace 2 or more spaces after `.`, `?` or `!` with one space only.

Comment: can be shortened to `sed -r 's/([.?!])\s+/\1 /g' file`

Comment: Thanks. But would you kindly elaborate why so many round, square brackets you used? It's little confusing.

Comment: @spasic: That's work with GNU sed only, updated with simplified version.

Comment: @Zeus: That's standard syntax with default BRE.

Comment: No, the original `sed` editing script will replace any line containing a single space with the literal string `^$`.

Comment: Sentence can be quoted so to be more general a little modification `\([.?!]["'\'']\?\)` or `\([.?!][\x22\x27]\?\)`

Comment: @Costas: Yep, that's what I said, depend on what characters mark end of sentence. Also not that require GNU sed to recognize `\xXX` sequences.

Answer (score 7):

This is what you might be looking for,

```
tr -s " " <filename
```

Sample,

```
$ echo "This is the output.  Hello Hello" | tr -s "[:blank:]"
This is the output. Hello Hello
```

Using `sed`,

```
$ echo "This is the output.  Hello Hello" | sed 's/\. \+/. /g'
$ echo "This is the output.  Hello Hello" | sed 's/\. \{1,\}/. /g'
This is the output. Hello Hello
```

Comment: Well, it is working thanks, but I need to include the sed command. Kindly tell something similar to above shown, like substitution, change text etc in sed.

Comment: I wasn't aware of this tr feature,

Comment: This approach will replace two spaces which are not end of sentence, too.